# Touchpad scroll not working on HP Pavilion dm3 laptop

Tags: 11.10, laptop, touchpad, mouse-scroll, hp-pavilion

I have an HP Pavilion dm3 laptop running Ubuntu 11.10. My touchpad works perfectly fine, but with one exception, the scrolling does not work. Does anybody out there know of any sure-fire fix that exists out there?

Comment: Have you tried installing the "synaptiks" software from the install center? That's how I got my scroll portion of my touchpad to work on my Alienware.

Comment: open a terminal, type `xinput list`, identify how the touchpad is detected and add this to your question. This should help is giving more relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

The following commands fixed it for me (temporarily until reboot):

```
sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

And to make it permanent

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/options
```

Add this line:

```
options psmouse proto=imps
```

Source: http://puzzlescript.wordpress.com/2010/07/04/fix-scrolling-not-working-on-touchpad-in-ubuntu-10-04/

Note: This fix will make the touchpad be recognized as a mouse instead, which will remove some features specific to touchpads such as disable while typing.