# No Natural Scrolling

Tags: mouse, 17.04, mouse-scroll

Running Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 on a HP Laptop with touchpad.

I am able to click by tapping the touchpad, right click by tapping it with two fingers.

But scrolling direction does not change irrespective of whether Settings -> Mouse -> Natural Scrolling is ON or OFF.

One interesting observation - if I use Gnome on Wayland, Natural Scrolling works perfectly. Gnome on Wayland also has more detailed settings available under 'Mouse' category.

How do I get the natural scrolling working even in normal Gnome?

Comment: See [this page:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106374/touchpad-scroll-not-working-on-hp-pavilion-dm3-laptop)

Comment: @Redbob Thanks. But that is a pretty old post (11.10 vis-a-vis 17.04). The file `/etc/modprobe.d/options` does not even exist on my computer! Moreover, it will not let me disable touchpad while typing. And that is a bad compromise :(

Comment: Unfortunately, the applied method I comment days ago didn't worked. When I run `xinput list` and `xinput list-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"`, I haven't found Natural Scrolling, different to [this page example](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=11445). So dconf-editor will not work at all.

Comment: If you follow commands I exampled above and see this prop, can apply [this suggestion](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2017/02/23/enable-natural-scrolling-for-trackpads-using-libinput/).  It may works for you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: You can consider [my answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707365/318461) - is it suitable to be posted here? [The solution provided by Redbob](https://askubuntu.com/a/961704/830570) yielded no effect/was ignored on my system for some reason. [This U&L Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307928/318461) could also be relevant.

Answer (score 4):

As I also have a HP laptop right now, I decided to dedicate myself to solve this problem. I made tests in Lubuntu, Gnome Classic, Gnome in Wayland and Lubuntu. Tests was made with `dconf-editor`,  System Properties > Mouse & Launchpad and line-command `xinput`.

These commands **must not be executed with sudo**, because they must reflect to user settings. Using sudo will not have any effect to changes.

**Lubuntu**

In Lubuntu we don't have *Natural Scrolling* prop listed by `xinput`. At other hand, we have *two-finger scrolling*, this is able to change touchpad behavior.

- `xinput list` to recognize which id is relactive to SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad; In my case the ID is 11.
- `xinput list-props 11`. It gaves me `Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (303)`

So I set:

- `xinput set-prop 11 303 1 1` to enable;
- `xinput set-prop 11 303 0 0` to disable.

**Gnome in Wayland**

Commands [related by deshmukn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960955/no-natural-scrolling#comment1535808_960955) worked as expected. In this interface, they worked;

**Gnome Classic**

Different than Lubuntu, there is *Natural Scrolling* in xinput list-prop, but it has no effect to device, no regarding set you choose in `dconf-editor` of System settings.

To enable/disable Natural Scrolling, you must do a combination of two features: `Scroll-method` and `two-finger-scrolling`.

To enable it:

- switch `scroll-method` to **two-finger-scrolling**;
- switch `two-finger-scrolling-enable` to **true**;

[image]

To disable it:

- switch `scroll-method` to **disabled**;
- switch `two-finger-scrolling-enable` to **false**;

[image]

Comment: sudo dconf-editor sets defaults for root, not the user. Please fix. (and using sudo in this case is also a mistake.

Comment: @redbob No. That is not it. Plus, mistakes as doug pointed out.

Comment: Look, deshmukh, I edited my answer. You didn't even noticed it. Before @doug comment, I told `sudo dconf-editor`. After that, I deleted my answer, did all tests again last night (it took me 2 hours) without sudo and undeleted it. @doug was sure. `dconf-editor` is present at Gnome menu and must be launched by single user, because sudo won't reflect to user environment. Did you try to set it?

Comment: I don't think OP is using Synaptics user space driver.